# Error 500 internal server ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Hola amigos resulta que estoy tratando de enviar unos datos por ajax en formato json por haciaq php. El código está funcionando y se ejecuta la inserción en la base de datos pero en la consola me sale este error:

```
POST http://localhost:8081/informe/Controlador/mes-controlador.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Pero cuando reviso la base de datos si se realiza la inserción. Probé  revisar el código php y no se porque ejecuta en la base de datos sino está recibiendo por post.

```js
 enviar_mes.submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //Obtener las sumas totales
        var datos={
            'horas':$('#suma_horas').text(),
            'publicaciones':$('#suma_publicaciones').text(),
            'revisitas':$('#suma_revisitas').text(),
            'videos':$('#suma_videos').text(),
            'usuario': usuario,
            'crear-mes': 'nuevo'
        }
        
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            data: datos,
            // tercer parámetro es la url adonde enviamos los datos
            url: 'Controlador/mes-controlador.php',
            // Cuarto parámetro es mediante que tipo de dato se envía : JSON
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var respuesta = data;
                if (respuesta.respuesta=='Informe-insertado') {
                    window.location.href="Vista/lista-meses";     
                }
            }
        });   
    });
```

```html
if(isset($_POST['crear-mes'])) {
        date_default_timezone_set("America/Bogota");
        $mes=date('F');
        $anio=date('Y');
        $usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
        $horas=(int)filter_var($_POST['horas'],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $publicaciones=(int)filter_var($_POST['publicaciones'],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $videos=(int)filter_var($_POST['videos'],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $revisitas=(int)filter_var($_POST['revisitas'],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
      
        $objMes=new Mes();
        $objMes->setHoras($horas);
        $objMes->setPublicaciones($publicaciones);
        $objMes->setVideos($videos);
        $objMes->setRevisitas($revisitas);
        $objMes->setMes($mes);
        $objMes->setAnio($anio);
        $objMes->setUsuario($usuario);
    
        $mes=new Mes();
        $mes->setHoras($objMes->getHoras());
        $mes->setPublicaciones($objMes->getPublicaciones());
        $mes->setVideos($objMes->getVideos());
        $mes->setRevisitas($objMes->getRevisitas());
        $mes->setMes($objMes->getMes());
        $mes->setAnio($objMes->getAnio());
        $mes->setUsuario($objMes->getUsuario());

        $insercion=$mes->insertar_mes();
    
        if ($insercion){
            $respuesta=array(
                'respuesta'=>'Informe-insertado',
                'mes'=>$mes->getMes()(),
                'horas'=>$mes->getHoras(),
                'publicaciones'=>$mes->getPublicaciones(),
                'videos'=>$mes->getVideos(),
                'revisitas'=>$mes->getRevisitas(),
                'mes'=>$mes->getEstudios(),
                'año'=>$mes->getAnio()
            );      
        }
        else {
            $respuesta=array(
                'respuesta'=>'Informe no registrado'
            );
        }
        
        die(json_encode($respuesta));   
}
```

Como les decía al principio el código está funcionando pero me manda ese error 500. He estado mirando pero no sé que pasa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes error de sintaxis. Has puesto los paréntesis de invoación del método 2 veces.

```
$respuesta=array(
                'respuesta'=>'Informe-insertado',
                'mes'=>$mes->getMes()(), <-- sobran parentesis
                'horas'=>$mes->getHoras(),
                'publicaciones'=>$mes->getPublicaciones(),
                'videos'=>$mes->getVideos(),
                'revisitas'=>$mes->getRevisitas(),
                'mes'=>$mes->getEstudios(),
                'año'=>$mes->getAnio()
            );
```